# Is it possible to modify a movss or xmm# in Assembly using Cheat Engine?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, cheat-engine

Im using cheat engine as a beginner to getting into Disassembly and Hacking, and I want to know how to modify an address/pointer (not really sure how to term it) thats using a `movss [...],xmm#`?

Specifically, Im modifying the Health in Satisfactory.

Fall damage causes the `movss [rbx+00000164],xmm0` to fire, `xmm0` represents the amount of health subtracted from the damage of falling.

Then it sends `xmm0` to `rbx+000000164`.

That causes the health to go down. I want it to go Up, or not lose/gain any at all.

I tried seeing if there were any xmm#s in the scanner that lined up with max health (100) to see if I could just send the player's max health every time they took damage (This would solve it easily)

However, it doesnt have it.
As seen here:
[image]

I was following a tutorial https://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Tutorials:Auto_Assembler:Injection_full, but they made it super simple, mentioning only...

> Now the easiest thing to do here, since the code already adds is to just make the number positive.

Thats not very informing, they were lucky, their value is just a number that can be set to positive or negative, or just be modified.

Mine cant.

**So the big question is, is there anything I can do to modify or change it? I need to make this simpler.**

By the way, heres my script that Im using to actually "hack" the health. All it does right now is the default xmm0 send, basically it does nothing.

```
{ Game   : FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe
  Version: 
  Date   : 2020-03-15
  Author : taylo

  This script does blah blah blah
}

define(address,"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3AA)
define(bytes,F3 0F 11 83 64 01 00 00)

[ENABLE]
//code from here to '[DISABLE]' will be used to enable the cheat



assert(address,bytes)
alloc(newmem,$1000,"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3AA)

label(code)
label(return)

newmem:

code:
  movss [rbx+00000164],xmm0
  jmp return

address:
  jmp newmem
  nop 3
return:

[DISABLE]
//code from here till the end of the code will be used to disable the cheat
address:
  db bytes
  // movss [rbx+00000164],xmm0

dealloc(newmem)

{
// ORIGINAL CODE - INJECTION POINT: "FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3AA

"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E376: 49 89 6B B0              -  mov [r11-50],rbp
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E37A: 4D 89 73 A8              -  mov [r11-58],r14
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E37E: E8 BD D5 FB FF           -  call FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe+8CB940
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E383: 0F 28 C8                 -  movaps xmm1,xmm0
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E386: 0F 2F 0D 53 B9 64 02     -  comiss xmm1,[FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe+2F59CE0]
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E38D: 0F 82 B9 00 00 00        -  jb FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe+90E44C
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E393: F3 0F 10 83 64 01 00 00  -  movss xmm0,[rbx+00000164]
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E39B: F3 0F 5F CE              -  maxss xmm1,xmm6
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E39F: 0F B6 83 6C 01 00 00     -  movzx eax,byte ptr [rbx+0000016C]
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3A6: F3 0F 5C C1              -  subss xmm0,xmm1
// ---------- INJECTING HERE ----------
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3AA: F3 0F 11 83 64 01 00 00  -  movss [rbx+00000164],xmm0
// ---------- DONE INJECTING  ----------
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3B2: A8 01                    -  test al,01
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3B4: 75 4C                    -  jne FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe+90E402
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3B6: A8 02                    -  test al,02
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3B8: 74 1D                    -  je FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe+90E3D7
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3BA: 48 89 6C 24 28           -  mov [rsp+28],rbp
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3BF: 4C 8B CF                 -  mov r9,rdi
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3C2: 0F 28 D1                 -  movaps xmm2,xmm1
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3C5: 4C 89 74 24 20           -  mov [rsp+20],r14
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3CA: 48 8B D6                 -  mov rdx,rsi
"FactoryGame-Win64-Shipping.exe"+90E3CD: 48 8B CB                 -  mov rcx,rbx
}
```

Comment: In DMC5, there's a similar instruction that uses movss and xmm2. I tried putting (float)### but it doesnt work. It says an error in line 12, which is the instruction line. then I changed movss to mov and it worked. game didn't crash which was great, but I still curious about what's the correct way to deal with movss.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit more research, and help from a friend, I figured it out.

the `movss` and `mov` are **opcodes** and its usually in the form of a **float** (for movss atleast)

So, hence, you CAN change its value.

Simply write `movss [..address..],(float)###` replace ### with your number.

As for my question, it works, I have disabled the entire game's health decrement. Making all creatures and players invulnerable forever using the same method.

As seen here by MY use of it:

**Yes, I know it was about modifying the movss, but my value IS a float, its just stored in the "form" of an Integer, so it uses mov, you can use this same movss code.**

```
code:
  mov [rbx+00000164],(float)100
  jmp return
```

`mov` is like saying `move`, it moves the value in the operand and sends it to the address.

So its as simple as moving a number. I just had bad formatting, and didnt realise you had to specify the data type via something like `(float)`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky No problem, although, I honestly didnt expect it to be as easy as just specifying a single word. As I do more and more of this, it seems to make more sense.